# A set containment in Measure and Category, Oxtoby

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

[image]

Three hours trying to see why this is true, I've pretty much given up. Are there any hints to see why this containment holds?

Answer (score 0):

Oxtoby is using $-$ for set difference (more commonly denoted $\backslash$ these days).  We have $I \subseteq G$, and $A = G \Delta P = (G \cap P^c) \cup (G^c \cap P)$.
$$[(x+I) \cap I] - [ P \cup (x+P)] = (x+I) \cap I \cap (P \cup (x+P))^c 
= (x+I) \cap (x+P)^c \cap I \cap P^c$$
and $I \cap P^c \subseteq G \cap P^c \subseteq A$.  Translating by $x$, 
$(x+I) \cap (x+P)^c = x + (I \cap P^c) \subseteq x + A$.
So 
$$(x+I) \cap (x+P)^c \cap I \cap P^c \subseteq A \cap (x+A)$$
as required.

Comment: That explains my difficulties. That notation combined with the fact that I'm using this to prove a statement about $S - S = \{s_{1} - s_{2} | s_{1}, s_{2} \in S \}$ combined yet again with the fact that Oxtoby himself is using $+$ in an analogous way to how I'm using $-$, I never considered that for a second.